# ajax php function call works only first call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the below function which is calling a PHP file with a function which returns in Json format the results which i get and assign in Javascript values as shown below. The php function is fully working and checked. The results are send and kept in the variables until i change the market var from the update_tipster function.

I have 8 tabs which send data to the function update_tipster. As soon as i press on the first 4 tabs where the market1 is blank everything works great. When i press  the other 4 tabs i get no response from the ajax and i get white page. When i try it and load the market1 as 'gh_' which is the value of the other 4-7 tabs everything again is working for the tabs 5-8 but for 0-3 is blank.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-0" onclick="update_tipster( '0', '', market_id, date_today)">
            <img src="betfair/img/horse-icon-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:5px;">ALL PLANS</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="update_tipster( '1', '', market_id, date_today )" >
            <img src="betfair/img/horse-icon-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:5px;">MASTER</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="update_tipster( '2', '', market_id, date_today )" >
            <img src="betfair/img/horse-icon-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:6px;">PHANTOM</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" onclick="update_tipster( '3', '', market_id, date_today )" >
            <img src="betfair/img/horse-icon-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:6px;">LAY LOSERS</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4" onclick="update_tipster( '4', 'gh_', market_id, date_today )" >
            <img src="betfair/img/dog-icon-orange-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:6px;">ALL PLANS</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5" onclick="update_tipster( '5', 'gh_', market_id, date_today )" >
            <img src="betfair/img/dog-icon-orange-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:6px;">MASTER</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-7" onclick="update_tipster( '7', 'gh_', market_id, date_today )" >
            <img src="betfair/img/dog-icon-orange-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:6px;">PHANTOM</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-6" onclick="update_tipster( '6', 'gh_', market_id, date_today )" >
            <img src="betfair/img/dog-icon-orange-small.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <span style="padding-left:6px;">LAY LOSERS</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Javascript:

```
Function run_ajax(market, market_id1, tipster_id1, date_today1) {
market_type=market;

if(market_id1 === '0')
    {

    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST', 
              url: "betfair/market_blank_datetime.php",
              data: "market_type="+market,
              cache: false,
              async: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data1){
                date_today=data1.date_today;
                startTime_time=data1.startTime_time;
                market_id=data1.market_id_time;
              }
        });
    }
}

function update_tipster(tipster1, market1, market_id1, date_today1){
    tipster_id = tipster1;

    if(market_type != market1)
    {   
        market_type = market1;
        market_id='0';
    }
        runscript_menu();
        run_ajax(market_type, market_id, tipster_id, date_today1);
}
```

Comment: Your images should be closed with `/>`.

Comment: You should send the parameters in an object

data:{market_type:market}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, i used Jquery.ajax instead of $.ajax and is working great now. Thank You for your time

Answer (score 0):

`market_id1` is not used in `update_tipster()`, did you forget to concat a string?